# Linear density variation on a 2D plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

Here's my problem:

- on a 2-dimensionnal plane, I know the $x$, $y$ coordinates of 3 points $A, B, C$
- each point comes with an associated density $T$, that can vary from infinite minus to positive infinite
- $T$ values vary in a linear fashion depending on the location of the points,
  a linear gradient determines the local value of $T$

But,

- I don't know the gradient's **direction**, nor its **"rate" of variation**.

*What I'd like:*

I have a list:

```
Ax // horizontal coordinate of point A
Ay // vertical coordinate of point A
AT // value of T at point A
Bx // etc.
By
BT
Cx
Cy
CT
```

From this data I'd like to calculate for any point $E$ $(x,y)$ the value of $T$ at location $E$.

Comment: "T values vary in a linear fashion depending on the location of the points, a linear gradient determines the local value of T"

Can you provide any more detail on the gradient? Is it constant? (i.e. once you find the gradient in $T$ from, say, point $A$ to point $B$, does that value give you some information about the gradient everywhere?)

Comment: Yes, the gradient is constant - "linear" -, it is the same everywhere. I just want an algebric method to find the value of T for any coordinates `x, y`.  But from A to B is not sufficient, the gradient has a direction which is unknown and that I'd like to get...

Comment: the points A, B and C are NOT co-linear....

Comment: When you downvote my topic, why don't you post a comment?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes.

Comment: I'm not a professional, nor a student, this is not "homework" sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick one point at the reference point, and describe the other two as steps from it. Like

$$ (x_A,\,y_A) = (x_C+\Delta x_A,\,y_C + \Delta y_A) 
\\ (x_B,\,y_B) = (x_C+\Delta x_B,\,y_C + \Delta y_B) $$

the find the determinant of the system with $D = \Delta x_A \Delta y_B - \Delta x_B \Delta y_A$ and make sure it is $D\neq 0$, or the points are co-linear.

Find the slopes in the $(x,y)$ directions

$$ e_x = \frac{ (T_A-T_C) \Delta y_B - (T_B-T_C) \Delta y_A}{D}
\\ e_y = \frac{ (T_B-T_C) \Delta x_A - (T_A-T_C) \Delta x_B}{D} $$

(edit: e_y should start (T_B-T_C) )

and now your value is

$$ \boxed{ T(x,y) = T_C + e_x (x-x_C) + e_y (y-y_C) }$$

### Example

```
A = (8, 6)    T_A = 11.3
B = (12, 3)   T_B = -8.2
C = (2, -1)   T_C = 0.7
```

$$ \Delta x_A = 8-2 = 6
\\ \Delta y_A = 6-(-1) = 7
\\ \Delta x_B = 12-2 = 10
\\ \Delta y_B = 3-(-1) = 4
$$
    Check $D= (6)(4)-(10)(7) = -46 \neq 0 $

$$ e_x = \frac{(11.3-0.7)\,4 - (-8.2-0.7)\, 7}{-46} = -2.2761
\\ e_y = \frac{(-8.2-0.7)\,6-(11.3-0.7)\,10}{-46} = 4.4652
$$

So now $$T(x,y) = 0.7 -2.2761 (x-2) + 4.4652 (x+1)$$

Comment: There are more complex ways of doing this, using 2D vectors or even using homogeneous coordinates for something called a barycenter, but the direct component wise equations are the most straight forward to code into an algorithm.

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH, just a note, in the formulae for e_y, it should start with (Tb-Tc), not (Tb-Ta)!

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, I usually do it with matrices in Excel but I couldn't code it in C++, now I can, thkx!!

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction.